# Blogs disappear when post is liked

Tags: python, django

the code is working without any issues but the problem is that after I like a post instead of the like button changing the entire for loop having the posts stops functioning. ie there is nothing displayed other than the users username. The server doesn't throw any particular error it just doesn't display the for loop. I feel its an issue with the render part but I'm not quite sure what exactly is wrong with it

---

below are my files

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Blog
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class BlogsList(ListView):
    model=Blog
    template_name='blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='blogs'
    ordering=['-date_posted']



def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked=False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked=True
    context={
    'is_liked':is_liked
    }   
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url():
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.BlogsList.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post')
```

### ]

and home.html

```
{{ user.username }}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in blogs %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% if is_liked %}
              <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Unlike</button>
              {% else %}
              <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
              {% endif %}
            </form>
          </div>
        </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your render in like view doesn't have the post queryset required to render the view; I would suggest just redirecting to the home after successful like, i.e. `from django.shortcuts import redirect` and replace `render` with `return redirect("blog-home")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly use the redirect shortcut instead of render because render will not going to show all the post. You can either pass all the post in like view or simply call the list view by redirecting it.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def like_post(request, blog_id):
    # rest of code
    return redirect(post.get_absolute_url()) # redirect will going to call the BlogsList and your all post will be rendered
```

Comment: I initially did that but it didnt allow me to pass the is_liked as context

Comment: it's actually a very confusing situation, because you are directly accesing it you view via request.user and that will only going to work for single post not for all, maybe you can use a url for post-detail page and after that in that page you can easily perform this operation.

Comment: @4545 if you want to achieve something like post detail page then let me know I have something similar to that, and if you think this answer helped you then try considering it as your answer, thanks

Comment: can you show me what you mean by post-detail view? I mean will it display the like button on the home page for the posts?

Comment: The post-detail view will be separate view from home view. You can put an anchor tag in your template to go to a specific post, this will shorten the size of you home page and it will be going to help you to do some advanced stuff with your detail view because you will be going to have only one single post their. What do you think about this implementation, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When you click like button, your code is rendering from `like_post` view. In that view, context has no data called blogs. at the end of like_post, you should redirect to your BlogsListView instead of returning a HttpResponse.

you can use a django shortcut function [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to do this.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
#...
#...
#... your code
def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

Also, you need to figure out some way to get is_liked context in home itself. consider checking documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: thats the actual issue im not being able to pass the context to the template